# Request to re-open "Rotated ICs on PCB board"

Tags: discussion, review-queue

Apologies if this is not the way to go about this.

I've edited [the question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/302919/) to open it to the true question at its heart (it's not a dupe of the 45º orientation question as one comment suggested), I've dramatically expanded my own answer to the OP and particularly WHY neither the Q or my A is not a matter of opinion, but rather a solid engineering efficiency approach, and then requested a review, so far to no response in 3 days.

I'd like Enric Blanco, laptop2d, Rev1.0, Bence Kaulics, & DerStrom8 to reconsider their vote to close this question, please.

Comment: This is not the way to go about this. You should click the "reopen" button below the question, which will place it on the queue for the community reviewers to take another look at it.

Comment: Already done that.

Comment: If that doesn't work then use the "Ask a moderator" chat feature, you can talk directly to the moderator. But they'd probably tell you the same thing. If you can come up with a valid reason (searching the meta and help center) you'll be more convincing and you'll educate yourself on how the community make decisions.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have voted to close the question (soliciting opinions) because it was specifically asking about one particular product and wasn't asking a more general question about why some components on a PCB might be spun at odd angles. The question itself had this in it: -

> Some claimed it is bad, some claimed it is optimized. Most just say it
>   looks weird and drives them crazy.

So, it definitely looks like opinions are being generated with no general consensus on why. And, just because there might be a very plausible answer to a bad question, it doesn't mean that the question should not be closed.

Comment: To be fair to the OP, that last sentence, "Most just say it looks weird and drives them crazy" is an addition by the editor who is requesting to reopen the question. Honestly, it doesn't make the question look like it should be reopened, quite the opposite!

Comment: @EnricBlanco Wrong. I - the editor of the Q - did NOT add "Most just say it looks weird and drives them crazy", because that would be a rather unhelpful addition to the question.

Comment: @Techydude If that's true, then the edition history must be wrong - because it clearly reflects just that: you added that sentence. Either way, you could remove that sentence to have a better chance of reopening (hey, just my 2 cents).